# Finding closed form for double summation binomial

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

I am trying to find a closed form for the following double summation.

$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \sum_{m=0}^{N-n} \binom{n}{m}\binom{N-n}{m} x^n y^m$

It seems to be like Vandermonde's identity. Can anyone provide any suggestion?

Comment: Have you made any progress? What have you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not make much progress. I tried to write as follow but it does not help $(1+y)^{N-n} = \sum_{m=0}^{N-n} \binom{N-n}{m}  y^m$.

Comment: This can trivially be transformed into $$=\sum_{n=0}^N x^n\sum_{m=n}^N\binom{n}{N-m}\binom{N-n}{N-m}y^{N-m} = \sum_{m=0}^N\sum_{n=0}^m \binom{n}{N-m}\binom{N-n}{N-m} x^n y^{N-m}$$ but I haven't been successful from there

Comment: what makes you think this sum has a closed form?